# API validation errors not showing In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to make a post request to my Laravel post endpoint but I am not getting any validation errors.

**Controller**

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function adminLogin(AdminLoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password'), 'role' => 'admin'
        ])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

**API Route**

```php
Route::post('/admin/jamisi/login', 'Api\Admin\Auth\LoginController@adminLogin');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

**AdminLoginRequest**

```
class AdminLoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.required' => 'The Email Field Is required.',
            'email.unique' => 'The Email Has Already Been Taken.',
            'password.required' => 'The Password Field Is Required',
        ];
    }

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
    }
}
```

When I try to test with Postman I get a '401 Unauthorised error.' The validation errors are not showing.

Comment: You presumably need to be authorized to call this endpoint?

Comment: @ceejayoz No. it is a login request so you do not need to be authorised.

Comment: For every public request that no need to be authorized, set function `authorize()` to return false in your custom FormRequest. Actually Laravel will invoke that function first before running the validation process.

Comment: @PatrickObafemi the response code indicates otherwise. Is it possible that you are assigning the auth middleware in the constructor of the controller (like some of the default Laravel [auth controllers do](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c15a5ee0d205ade08ad86174cb9c38aafd2bd226/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php#L37)) and not adding an [exception](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c15a5ee0d205ade08ad86174cb9c38aafd2bd226/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php#L37) to the `adminLogin` method?

Comment: No i am not assigning the auth middleware and I am not adding any exception to the adminLogin method

Comment: @DharmaSaputra I am pretty sure that's not the case. Well i tried doing so and I get  'You are not authorised' response

Comment: @PatrickObafemi can you include the rest of the controller? Is it possible that the route is defined inside a middleware group that uses auth? Since your controller actually returns the 401 if Auth::attempt fails, it could also be possible that there's a simple error in the credentials being sent

Comment: @PatrickObafemi can you please also add your routes declaration?

Comment: @TravisBritz Thank you. I have updated my controller. When i input a correct credential I get the success token. So i am pretty sure it's not a middleware issue

Comment: @DharmaSaputra alright. Done that

Comment: So you mean the validation is not showing even you test it with Postman and submit empty email and password value?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra yes. That's what i am saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *validation* errors for an incorrect password (instead of an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response), then you need to change what your controller method does when `Auth::attempt` returns false:

```
if (Auth::attempt(...) {
        //...
} else {
    throw \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
```

This is similar to how the framework's login controller handles failed authentication: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L133

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
```

and add this on your top adminLogin function..No need to check unique email.because here you only check the email not register

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',

        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {

        $message = $validator->errors()->first();
        $errors=$validator->errors();
        $code='200';

        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $message,
            "errors" => $errors
        );

        return new JsonResponse($response, $code);

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I still get unauthorised and I still want to use a request Class.

Answer (score 0):

Send application/vnd.api+json as Accept header.